# Remotely connect to SQL Server through Java from an untrusted domain with Windows authentication

Tags: java, sql-server, authentication, wmi, windows-authentication

I am trying to remotely connect to SQL Server from a remote machine on an untrusted domain (I am not on the same domain as the host with the SQL server). The SQL Server is using Windows authentication and I can't change that. I am not allowed to make any manual changes to that remote machine like using SQL authentication. I can't add my machine to trusted domain(At least not manually). Currently using WMI I am able to access registry, etc. I know using runas /netonly command I can pretend I am on that machine but I can't use this command as it has to be all Java. I know with WMI I'll be able to connect to that machine having its ip/password and get different type of information but is there away to run SQL queries and all as well? Or any other solution using Java?
P.S. currently of course, I am getting "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't connect to SQL Server through Java remotely when not being in the same domain and only having the Windows Authentication option. So I ended up changing the security option manually in SQL Server management Studio to both using SQL user and Windows Authentication. This way I could connect to it using the SA!